# vscode terminal showing weird character in mac's terminal names

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, terminal

[vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWoTx.png)
here in this picture is showing weird characters between terminal's name in my macbook

I tried quitting vscode multiple times and tried various option. But none matches to this problem